# Codeigniter, testing if file uploader has file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following code in my view:

```
if (isset($stockists)) {
    $id = $stockists->ID;
    echo form_open_multipart($system_settings['admin_folder'].'/stockists/form/'.$id);
} 
else {
    echo form_open_multipart($system_settings['admin_folder'].'/stockists/form/');
}

 <?php echo "<input type='file' name='userfile' size='20' />"; ?>
```

There's lots of other text input fields in there that are sent to a database on submit. The file up loader is what I'm interested in though.

In my controller function, how can I check if a file exists in the up-loader after submit?

The following retruns false:
`$image = ($_FILES['userfile']);`

I need to check in a conditional statement if a file exists in the uploader. So for example:

```
if ($_FILES['userfile']) {
  //do
}
```

But this method does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The super global $_FILES

`$_FILES['userfile']` isn't a boolean.

```
if (strlen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > 0) {
    // Yes, is uploaded
}
```

In the array, you've also `error`:

```
echo $_FILES['userfile']['error'];
```

### CodeIgniter Approach

CodeIgniter has an upload class that can do the work for you.

> CodeIgniter's File Uploading Class permits files to be uploaded. You can set various preferences, restricting the type and size of the files.

Below an example from the CodeIgniter documentation:

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }

    function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

See for full examples the documentation: [CI File Upload Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)